# Identifying and collecting consecutive ranges from an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, range

### Task

Given `int[]` arrays such as I have to identify consecutive ranges and build a corresponding `String`

Another example would be

---

### Notes

I can assume that the array is already **ordered** and there are **no overlaps** in the ranges.

Also, the array **might be empty**.

---

### Ideas

I know how to build a string that just lists all numbers, like `4, 5, 6, 8, 14, 15, 16` but I have no idea how to identify the ranges and especially how to add a `~` between them.

I thought maybe regex might be usefull here, but I am unsure.

Comment: "Should I use regex..?" - No, regular expressions are used for _finding_ patterns in strings and you have an array of numbers. So what you'd need to do is iterate over your array, find all occurences of consecutive numbers, get the first and last, add them to a string and add the tilde in between.

Comment: Iterate from left to right and build increasing ranges. Each time the range is ended, you conclude it and wrap it up.

Comment: On "how do I find consecutive numbers?": keep track of the first number that could form a range as well as the current and last number of your iteration. If the difference between "current" and "last" is > 1 then "last" is the end of the previous range and "current" is the start of the next range. Now just build the output accordingly and consider the 3 possible cases: 1) start and end numbers of a range are the same -> only print the number, 2) start and end have a difference of 1 -> decide whether to print `start,end` or `start~end`, 3) print `start~end` for the rest

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation

You can simply iterate from left to right and maintain ranges while doing so.

For that, just remember the **start of a range** and the **last value in each iteration**. Then you can easily figure out if a **range just stopped or is continuing**. If it stopped, **conclude the range and start the next**.

For the special case of an empty array, just add a simple `if` to the start of the method, to handle it separately.

---

### Build ranges

```
public static String buildRanges(int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(", ");

    int rangeStart = values[0];
    int lastValue = values[0];
    // Skip first value to simplify 'lastValue' logic
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        int value = values[i];

        if (value != lastValue + 1) {
            // Range ended, wrap it up
            int rangeEnd = lastValue;
            result.add(rangeStart == rangeEnd
                ? Integer.toString(rangeStart)
                : rangeStart + "~" + rangeEnd);
            rangeStart = value;
        }

        lastValue = value;
    }

    // Conclude last range
    int rangeEnd = lastValue;
    result.add(rangeStart == rangeEnd
            ? Integer.toString(rangeStart)
            : rangeStart + "~" + rangeEnd);

    return result.toString();
}
```

##### Simplify

To tackle the code duplication and to improve readability, I would suggest to also introduce a helper method `rangeToString`:

```
public static String rangeToString(int rangeStart, int rangeEnd) {
    return rangeStart == rangeEnd
        ? Integer.toString(rangeStart)
        : rangeStart + "~" + rangeEnd);
}
```

The code then simplifies to:

```
public static String buildRanges(int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(", ");

    int rangeStart = values[0];
    int lastValue = values[0];
    // Skip first value to simplify 'lastValue' logic
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        int value = values[i];

        if (value != lastValue + 1) {
            // Range ended, wrap it up
            result.add(rangeToString(rangeStart, lastValue);
            rangeStart = value;
        }

        lastValue = value;
    }

    // Conclude last range
    result.add(rangeToString(rangeStart, lastValue);

    return result.toString();
}
```

---

### OOP solution

If you feel like, you can also introduce dedicated `Range` classes to solve this. Might be a bit overkill in this particular situation but still.

Let us first create a `Range` class that knows its start and end. Furthermore, it can convert itself to a `String` properly and you can attempt to increase the range.

```
public final class Range {
    private final int start;
    private int end;

    public Range(int value) {
        start = value;
        end = value;
    }

    public boolean add(int value) {
        if (value != end + 1) {
            return false;
        }
        end = value;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return start == end
            ? Integer.toString(start)
            : start + "~" + end;
    }
}
```

And now you can easily use that in a simple loop:

```
public static String buildRanges(int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(", ");

    Range range = new Range(values[0]);
    // Skip first value to simplify logic
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        int value = values[i];

        if (!range.add(value)) {
            // Range ended, wrap it up
            result.add(range.toString());
            range = new Range(value);
        }
    }

    // Conclude last range
    result.add(range.toString());

    return result.toString();
}
```

##### Collecting to `List<Range>`

This approach has the advantage that you can also collect to something like a `List<Range> ranges` and then continue working with the data, instead of only going to a `String`. Example:

```
public static List<Range> buildRanges(int[] values) {
    if (values.length == 0) {
        return List.of();
    }

    List<Range> ranges = new ArrayList<>();

    Range range = new Range(values[0]);
    // Skip first value to simplify logic
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
        int value = values[i];

        if (!range.add(value)) {
            // Range ended, wrap it up
            ranges.add(range);
            range = new Range(value);
        }
    }

    // Conclude last range
    ranges.add(range);

    return ranges;
}
```

In particular useful if you also add some `getStart()` and `getEnd()` method to the `Range` class.

---

### Notes

Note that the method will likely behave funky if the array contains **duplicates**. You did not specify what to do in that case, so I simply assumed duplicates will not exist for your use case.

Comment: if the array contains duplicates, better convert it to Set: '''  new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(values)));  ''' and then iterate

Comment: @AndrzejWięcławski You will lose the order of the array then though, which is kinda crucial. You can of course use `TreeSet` but then you made the effort of sorting twice, which is unecessary. If duplicates are a thing (OP did not specify), it is probably easier to just tackle them during the loop and simply skip them (the array is ordered, so skipping them is super simple).

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static String summary(int[] input) {
    int length = input.length;
    if (length == 0) return "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    new Object() {
        int start = input[0];
        int end = input[0];
        String separator = "";

        void append() {
            sb.append(separator).append(start);
            if (start != end)
                sb.append("~").append(end);
            separator = ", ";
        }

        void make() {
            for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
                int current = input[i];
                if (current != end + 1) {
                    append();
                    start = current;
                }
                end = current;
            }
            append();
        }
    }.make();
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(summary(new int[] {4, 5, 6, 8, 14, 15, 16}));
    System.out.println(summary(new int[] {13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 23, 24, 25, 100}));
}
```

output:

```
4~6, 8, 14~16
13~16, 21, 23~25, 100
```

Comment: Note that code-only answers are discouraged. An explanatiopn would be helpful.

Comment: The anonymous `Object` is kinda weird, a dedicated class would be preferable and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following `Interval` class:

```
public class Interval {
    public final int min;
    public final int max;

    public Interval(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public Interval(int minmax) {
        this(minmax, minmax);
    }

    public static List<Interval> toIntervals(int... values) {
        List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int val: values) {
            addInterval(list, val, val);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void addInterval(List<Interval> list, int min, int max) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < list.size()) {
            Interval cur = list.get(i);
            if (max < cur.min-1) {
                break;
            } else if (cur.max >= min-1) {
                min = Math.min(min, cur.min);
                max = Math.max(max, cur.max);
                list.remove(i);
            } else {
                ++i;
            }
        }
        list.add(i, new Interval(min, max));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (min == max) {
            return Integer.toString(min);
        }
        return min + "~" + max;
    }
}
```

You can convert the list of numbers in your examples to lists of intervals:

```
    List<Interval> list = Interval.toIntervals(4, 5, 6, 8, 14, 15, 16);
```

Or:

```
    List<Interval> list = Interval.toIntervals(13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 23, 24, 25, 100);
```

And print lists like that:

```
    System.out.println(list.stream()
            .map(Interval::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a int-to-string conversion, not a *cast*  in java sence which means `(TYPE2)OBJECTOFTYPE1` for instance int-to-double (*widening*) or Object-to-String.

The ranges one has to do oneself.

```
int[] a = {13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 23, 24, 25, 100};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (a.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(Integer.toString(a[i]));

        int rangeI = i;
        while (a[i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE && a[i] + 1 == a[i + 1]) {
            ++i;
        }
        if (i != rangeI) {
            sb.append('~').append(Integer.toString(a[i]));
        }
    }
}
return sb.toString();
```

You can do `append(a[i])` as there is an overloaded method that does internally a conversion. For clearity not done.

The separation by comma is quite standard.

And for every element check its range of increasing followers.

As java ignores integer overflow, the check on MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the integers to strings and append them using the StringBuilder class of Java: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stringbuilder-class-in-java-with-examples/

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
```

and append the numbers and '~' (tilda) sign by using:

```
str.append(start_number);
str.append('~');
str.append(end_number);
```

Comment: The real question is how to extract the ranges, not how to convert an int to a string.

Comment: Then iterating with a for loop and accumulate the range until reaching a number which the range between it and the next one is more than 1, and then appending with StringBuilder and resetting for the new range.

Comment: This answer is *not wrong* but it only focuses on probably the smallest and simplest part of the task. It is simply **incomplete**.

Comment: As the question was previously stated it seemed like he had trouble making the string itself. After edits and clarification it is obvious of course that he wanted the range itself.

Comment: I see, thats totally fair then. Its unfortunate that OP changed their question in a way that it made your answer look less good.